# write contents that display in browser to a file php?

Tags: php, file, text

I want to write contents that display in the browser to a text file. I want to display the data both in browser and write to a text file. Here is my script. I used file_put_contents to write to text file. But I can't see any data when I access my text file.

```
<?php
$dfile = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
while(!feof($dfile)) {
$mynextline = fgets($dfile);
if (preg_match("/lly/", $mynextline)) echo "$mynextline<br>";
}
$file = 'mycontent.txt'
file_put_contents($file, $mynextline);
?>
```

Comment: The piece of code you show is clearly incomplete. There's no `file_put_contents()`. Please add those details.

Comment: I'm sorry about that!. I have edited the file before I posted here.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php Alternatively you can put the output in a string and output it to the browser and the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would code it something like this

```
<?php
    $dfile = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
    $ob_file = fopen('mycontent.txt',"w");
    while(!feof($dfile)) {
        $mynextline = fgets($dfile);
        if (preg_match("/lly/", $mynextline)) {
            echo "$mynextline<br>";
            fwrite($ob_file, $mynextline);
        }
}

fclose($dfile);
fclose($ob_file);

?>
```

Comment: Now I understood. I need to open both the files that should be declared initially and then write the output to the text file. That's awesome and it worked!!

Comment: the problem was that with your lasts 2 lines, you were typing only the last string that you read. you need to write it in the while loop ;)

Comment: I understood @SpongePablo. Thank you very much. I will make a note when I write the script.